# Dompdf картинки и кириллица на линуксах

Tags: php, dompdf, файловые-пути

Проблема с хостингом, но куда копать не знаю. На VPS и на локалке всё работает, сравнивал phpinfo() - должно работать, но нет.

Есть одно отличие в путях - на рабочих пути

> C:\site.ru\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\fonts
> /var/www/***/data/www/site.ru/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts

на не рабочем по полному пути выдаёт ошибку и видит шрифт (не ругается на то что не найден) по пути от корня сайта

> /dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts